# wget cmd works in bash, but not in php

Tags: php, bash, wget

under bash shell the cmd works fine:

```
wget -qO- http://172.16.11.190/admin/resync?http://172.16.11.159/spa\$PSN.cfg > /dev/null
```

via apache log i see that $PSN is translated to 504G:

```
172.16.11.190 - - [20/Feb/2018:16:00:03 +0100] "GET /spa504G.cfg HTTP/1.1" 200 12696 "-" "Cisco/SPA504G-7.6.2c (E05FB98242D8)(CBT1504042O)"
```

when i running this command under php it doesn't work.

```
exec("wget -qO- http://$ip/admin/resync?http://172.16.11.159/spa\$PSN.cfg > /dev/null");
```

apache says:

```
172.16.11.190 - - [20/Feb/2018:16:08:56 +0100] "GET /spa.cfg HTTP/1.1" 404 464 "-" "Cisco/SPA504G-7.6.2c (E05FB98242D8)(CBT1504042O)"
```

The $PSN variable is missing/not translated. I believe that is a parsing error. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using single quotes instead of double-quotes in your php string.

Comment: Where do you set the $PSN variable?

Comment: Single quotes do not work.

Comment: $PSN is a variable from Cisco. It stands for Product Series Number. The phone picks the right provisioning file through it. And as i have written the command works well under bash.  The phone (by default) requests the file spa$psn.cfg (the phone replaces $psn with the model number, so for a 504G it will request spa504G.cfg)

Comment: When using single quotes, did you replace your `$ip` with the actual IP?

Comment: @kerbholz: if (isset($_POST['ip'])) {
 $ip = $_POST['ip'];
        exec('wget -qO- http://172.16.11.190/admin/resync?http://172.16.11.159/spa\$PSN.cfg > /dev/null');
       //exec('wget -qO- http://$ip/admin/resync?http://172.16.11.159/spa\$PSN.cfg > /dev/null');
}
when i hard code the ip it works with single quotes. But the $ip should be a variable.

Comment: Please do **NOT** post code in the comments, that's horrible to read. If it works using single quotes, use `'wget -qO- http://' . $ip . '/...` to use $ip. Kudos to @Calimero

Comment: @kerbholz: thank you next time i will do so. Your code works. Thanks to all for the support.

Comment: Don't put answers in questions. It stops the question being a question. Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Why would `'/' . $ip . '/'` work and `"/$ip/"` won't? They're identical for all intents and purposes.

Comment: You probably needed a few more '\' to make your original one work, may sound odd but `spa\\\$PSN.cfg` the first '\' escapes the second '\' and the third'\' escapes the '$'